# Not able to fetch data from apex imperitively to lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

In javascript file the file is not able to call the apex method, getbankinfo. it is failing and the logic is moving to catch.

JS:
// transactionRecordForm.js

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import createTransactionRecord from '@salesforce/apex/TransactionController.createTransactionRecord';
import getBankInfo from '@salesforce/apex/TransactionController.getBankInfo';

export default class TransactionRecordForm extends LightningElement {
    @track successCode;
    @track accountId;
    bankInfoList;
    connectedCallback() {
     
        this.accountId = '0015g00001b5s9aAAA';
    }

    handleSuccessCodeChange(event) {
        this.successCode = event.target.value;
        console.log ('success code', this.successCode);
        this.fetchMessage();
    }

    fetchMessage() {
        getBankInfo()
            .then(result => {
                 bankInfoList = result;
                
                const selectedBankInfo = bankInfoList.find(info => info.Success_Code__c === this.successCode);
                if (selectedBankInfo) {
                    this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field[data-field="Message__c"]').value = selectedBankInfo.Message__c;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching bank info: ', error);
            if (error && error.body && Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                // Log each error message in the response body
                error.body.forEach(err => console.error(err.message));
            }
            });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        createTransactionRecord({
            name: this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field[data-field="Name"]').value,
            successCode: this.successCode,
            accountId: this.accountId
        })
            .then(() => {
               
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error creating transaction record: ', error);
            });
    }

    handleSuccess() {
        
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<!-- transactionRecordForm.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Transaction Record Form">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Transaction__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" required></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Success_Code__c" required onchange={handleSuccessCodeChange}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Account__c" required></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Message__c" readonly></lightning-input-field>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Save"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

APEX

```java
public with sharing class TransactionController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Bank_Info__mdt> getBankInfo() {
        System.debug('Inside getbankinfo');
        return [SELECT Id,Success_Code__c, Message__c FROM Bank_Info__mdt ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createTransactionRecord(String name, String successCode, Id accountId) {
        List<Bank_Info__mdt> bankInfoList = getBankInfo();

        String message = '';
        for (Bank_Info__mdt bankInfo : bankInfoList) {
            if (bankInfo.Success_Code__c == successCode) {
                message = bankInfo.Message__c;
                break;
            }
        }

        Transaction__c newRecord = new Transaction__c(
            Name = name,
            Success_Code__c = successCode,
            Account__c = accountId,
            Message__c = message
        );
        insert newRecord;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.bankInfoList = result` instead of `bankInfoList = result`?

Comment: tried this but still the same error is coming up

Comment: You also added `this` to `const selectedBankInfo = bankInfoList`, right?

Comment: yes i added both the places and still the error is same